# Can't make Bokeh 0.11.0 work under QWebView environment

Tags: bokeh

I was using `Bokeh 0.10.0` and embed it into a `PySide QWebView widget` as a customized data visualizer, it works well on most of the parts. (some JS seems not supported by QWebKit and works weird)

But after I upgrade Bokeh to 0.11.0 and change some ATTRIBUTE names,
(background_color sort of stuff). it now can be work on Chrome browser, but complete fail on QWebKit.
(can't load the webpage)

Does any one counter this problem? Or it just not gonna support QWebKit anymore?

Comment: I should say that QWebKit has never officially been supported (in the sense that it is part of our CI testing). That said, we'd certainly like Bokeh to work in as many ways as possible, and I expect any regression here is simply due to the fact that none of the core devs use QWebKit at all, AFAIK. Given time/people/experience limitations, official support for QwebKit  would probably require a new maintainer to come help out. But I encourage you to open a GH issue, or come the the public mailing list with some code, to see if there is something quick that can be done to help in the short term.